# Handle HTML entity with Data Binding

Tags: android, html, data-binding, android-databinding

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.text.Html"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@{Html.fromHtml(`some message from model` + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`)}"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </layout>
```

Here I am trying to leave some blank space after text in `TextView`, but it is showing **this error**.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'. 
The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
```

I have tried with simple space in xml, but it doesn't leave blank spaces `android:text="@{'some message from model' + '      '}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@nbsp` and try with it `hexa(decimal)` value `&#160`.

because in XML the main five entity are below :

`quet(")`, `amp(&)`, `apos(')`, `It(<)` and `gt(>)` In which the `@nbsp` to not there so you need to use it hexa(decimal) value `&#160`.

If We have to put Space in XML using HTMl we use `&nbsp` But in Xml it give this error :

> The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.

Because the Main five entity of XMl is I define Upper so you have to use it hexa(decimal) value..

so `&nbsp` you have to `&#160`. but again `&` is XMl Entity so you have convert `&` to `&amp;` so it will work.

**In SHORT :**

`&nbsp` means `&amp;#160`

Comment: It shows `unexpected & or nonterminated character/entity reference`

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I assume you are written this way `&amp;#160` if not then change it.

Comment: yeah that works, thanks :) If you don't mind can you please add your comment of `&amp;#160` in answer? So that it can help others also.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya ya sure..I update my answer with brief see.